# Graph tool kit components usage in teams react application without login components

Tags: authentication, graph, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-toolkit

graph toolkit SSO without Login Component
in my teams tab i have followed the below link and authenticated Teams Tab.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso
I want to able to use graph tool kit with out Login component as i have sso for tab,

is it possible to do so?  if so can i call the graph toolkit components without login components

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can use the components with Teams SSO:

- If you already have authentication setup and you are able to get access tokens for  Graph calls, use the [SimpleProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/custom#simpleprovider) to allow the components to use your access tokens.
- If you do not have authentication setup, we have a new [Teams provider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/main/packages/providers/mgt-teams-sso-provider) in preview that enables SSO - this provider will be part of the 2.3 release.

  You can install it with the `next` tag: `npm i @microsoft/mgt-teams-sso-provider@next`. Make sure to also install any other mgt packages with the same tag/version to avoid any errors.

  Since SSO requires a backend service, take a look at our [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/main/samples/teams-sso-node), and let us know if you run into any issues.

Comment: UmaMaheshwari - Is your issue resolved or still looking for any other solution?

Comment: I tried using thw simple provider it didnt work.

Comment: The link to the posted discussion  [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/graph-toolkit-sso-without-login-component/m-p/2595925/highlight/false#M3581)
I have posted the same in discussion, If you provide solution  it would be help full

Comment: @UmamaheshwariG - Looks like your configuration is wrong for token validation "audience".
Could you please reverify & test it again.